# The SSL / TLS handshake between a "Java 1.7 TLS 1.2 server" and a "Java 1.6 client"

Tags: java, security, ssl, java-7, java-6

The SSL / TLS handshake between a `Java 1.7 TLS 1.2 server` and a `Java 1.6 client` fails with the following exception on the client side:

Getting below error from client end :

```
Remote host closed connection during handshake; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:418)
    at com.aviva.ukgi.gw.cc.midvehiclesearch.rest.MIDVehicleSearchServiceRest.executeMIDVehicleSearch_aroundBody0(MIDVehicleSearchServiceRest.java:69)
    at com.aviva.ukgi.gw.cc.midvehiclesearch.rest.MIDVehicleSearchServiceRest.executeMIDVehicleSearch_aroundBody1$advice(MIDVehicleSearchServiceRest.java:134)
    at com.aviva.ukgi.gw.cc.midvehiclesearch.rest.MIDVehicleSearchServiceRest.executeMIDVehicleSearch(MIDVehicleSearchServiceRest.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Server Side:

```
2015-10-20 10:24:17.454 | DEBUG | qtp525589302-1668 |  | org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl     | 94 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@1936d287 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@5e37a9ff,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2015-10-20 10:24:17.454 | DEBUG | qtp525589302-1668 |  | org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl     | 94 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] handle SslConnection@1936d287 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@5e37a9ff,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} progress=false
2015-10-20 10:24:17.470 | DEBUG | qtp525589302-1669 |  | org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl     | 94 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@1936d287 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=517/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@5e37a9ff,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=517/517 flushed=0/0
2015-10-20 10:24:17.471 | DEBUG | qtp525589302-1669 |  | org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl     | 94 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=517 produced=474
2015-10-20 10:24:17.471 | DEBUG | qtp525589302-1669 |  | org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl     | 94 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@1936d287 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@5e37a9ff,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the error on the server side?

Comment: Attached logs in server side.

Comment: You should set the property [`javax.net.debug`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) in the client application to get enough information to try to debug this.

Comment: Can you trace what protocols are enabled on the client side?

Comment: The client application uses oracle Jdk 1.6 and they use tls 1.0 by default I think...

Answer (score 1):

Please try below in Java 1.6 client:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1
```

or

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
```